Push Notification not working on Xamarin MAUI
I have configured success Firebase and got the device token, but when I use Postman to verify, the device doesn't show any notification.
Lib: Plugin.PushNotification

get device token ok
https://i.sstatic.net/Qk3LU.png

push via fcm api ok
https://i.sstatic.net/OFxHS.png

setting notification
https://i.sstatic.net/no5OA.jpg


but App not received any notification.
What is the problem?

Please check this there are a lot of missing details in your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Please add relevant project codes， this is helpful to check the cause of the problem.

Which platform are you using firebase on? What is the .Net version used by your MAUI project?
